# CMake is importing the wrong version of a library, used through a dependency, when it exists in different versions on the system

Tags: c++, cmake, dependency-management, find-package

I’m writing a static library LibA which has a `CMake` configuration file so that it can be found with `find_package`.
This lib is privately linking another one LibB which is also detected by a `find_package` command and exports `LibB::LibB`. This is a third party library so I cannot fiddle with it.
`CMake` provides a `FindLibB` (could be `OpenCV` for instance).

I’m building an executable SomeApp that is privately linking LibA.

My issue is that I'm working on windows, either with clang or gcc, or with msvc.
So I installed two version of `LibB`:

- a `msvc` compliant version
- a `msys2/gcc` compliant version

The msvc version has no CMake configuration file but it's path is in my user environment PATH.
The msys2 version has a CMake configuration file.

My development environment is organized like this:

```
dev
|-CMakeUtilities
|-CMakePackages
|-LibA
|   |-CMakeLists.txt
|-SomeApp
|   |-CMakeLists.txt
```

In my `LibA` project and its unit tests, I've implemented the following logic for exporting `LibA`:

```
# logic to determined LibB location
if(NOT(DEFINED ENV{LIBB_DIR}))
    # On windows with 2 installs: an msvc-compiled and a gcc-compiled one.
    if(${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID} STREQUAL MSVC)
        # MSVC
        if(DEFINED ENV{LIBB_DIR_msvc})
            set(ENV{LIBB_DIR} $ENV{LIBB_DIR_msvc})
        endif() 
    elseif(DEFINED ENV{LIBB_DIR_msys2})
        # gcc with msys2
        set(ENV{LIBB_DIR} $ENV{LIBB_DIR_msys2})
    else()
        message(WARNING "LIBB NOT FOUND OR NOT PROPERLY INSTALL")
    endif()
endif()
# creating the dependency
find_package(LIBB)
target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME} PRIVATE LIBB::LIBB)

# includes directories
target_include_directories(${TARGET_NAME} PUBLIC
$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${INCLUDE_PATH}>
$<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${INCLUDE_PATH}>
)
target_include_directories(${TARGET_NAME} PRIVATE
$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${SRC_PATH}/${TARGET_NAME}>
)

# Generating export file
include(GenerateExportHeader)
generate_export_header(${TARGET_NAME})
file(COPY ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${TARGET_NAME}_export.h DESTINATION ${INCLUDE_PATH})

# REQUIRED_DEPENDENCIES is used to list all my dependencies for the config fil generation
set(MY_REQUIRED_DEPENDENCIES)
list(APPEND MY_REQUIRED_DEPENDENCIES LIBB)
configure_file(${DEV_DIR_REL_PATH}/ModuleConfig.cmake.in ${TARGET_NAME}Config.cmake @ONLY)
unset(MY_REQUIRED_DEPENDENCIES)

# Target output path
set_target_properties(${TARGET_NAME} PROPERTIES RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${LIB_PATH}/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE})
set_target_properties(${TARGET_NAME} PROPERTIES ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${LIB_PATH}/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE})

# Installation
install (
TARGETS ${TARGET_NAME}
EXPORT ${TARGET_NAME}Targets
LIBRARY DESTINATION ${INSTALL_LIB_PATH}/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}
ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${INSTALL_LIB_PATH}/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}
RUNTIME DESTINATION ${SHAREDLIB_PATH}
PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION ${INSTALL_INCLUDE_PATH}
)
install (
EXPORT ${TARGET_NAME}Targets
NAMESPACE ${TARGET_NAME}::
DESTINATION ${CMAKEPACKAGE_PATH}
)
# Install the ${TARGET_NAME}Config.cmake
install(FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${TARGET_NAME}Config.cmake"
DESTINATION ${CMAKEPACKAGE_PATH}
)
```

And here is `ModuleConfig.cmake.in`:

```
include(CMakeFindDependencyMacro)
foreach(_lib_ IN ITEMS @MY_REQUIRED_DEPENDENCIES@)
    find_dependency(${_lib_} REQUIRED)
endforeach()

# include the generated target file
include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/@TARGET_NAME@Targets.cmake")
```

- `DEV_DIR_REL_PATH` is the relative path from `CMakeLists.txt` to the `dev` directory.
- `CMAKEPACKAGE_PATH` is the full path to `dev/CMakePackages`
- `INCLUDE_PATH` is the full path, ending with `includes`, to `LibA` includes
- `LIB_PATH` is the full path, ending with `libs`, to `LibA` binary
- `INSTALL_INCLUDE_PATH` is just includes
- `INSTALL_LIB_PATH` is just `libs`
- `SHAREDLIB_PATH` is the full path to a single directory where I install the dynamic library I'm creating. I think it's meaningless here if `LibA` is a static library, but I'm trying to make my `CMakeLists.txt` as generic as possible.

I also set these environment variables.

- LIBB_DIR_msvc=<PathToLibB_msvc>
- LIBB_DIR_msys2=C:/<Msys2Path>/ucrt64/lib/cmake/

NB `C:/<Msys2Path>/ucrt64/bin` is also on my path.

All my projects are using `set(CMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_PREFER_CONFIG TRUE)`

This is the dependency declaration in `SomeApp`' `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
find_package(LibA REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME} PRIVATE LibA::LibA)
```

For sake of readability, I omitted, in my snippet, a few paths declarations that are telling were `LibA` files could be found.

---

When using msvc, `LibA` is correctly compiling, as its unit tests, that are running fine. But when I’m trying to build `SomeApp`, the linker is complaining that `LibB` symbols are undefined.

Looking at the build command created by `CMake`, I see that it is trying to link the `msys2/gcc` version, which is, of course, wrong.
Looking at `LibA` CMake configuration file I only see `LINK_ONLY:LibB::LibB` without any references to the actual library directories.

My Guess is that, in `SomeApp`, CMake is doing a `find_package`, in `CONFIG` mode and it's finding the `msys2` version through `C:/<Msys2Path>/ucrt64/lib`, though I don't know why it would look inside this directory.

Here is a sumup of the issue.

- `LibB` is present as `msvc` and `msys2` versions:

  - `msvc/LibB`
  - `msys2/LibB`
- `LibA` private-depends on `msvc/LibB`
- `SomeApp` private-depends on `LibA`
- `SomeApp` is erroneously linked against `msys2/LibB`

I don’t understand how to fix it. I naively thought that when I declared a dependency, it’s path were registered also.

I though about two possible solutions:

1. Exporting to `LibA` configuration file the logic to find `LibB`: don’t know how, risk of conflicting link in case of diamond-like dependency.
2. Overriding `FindLibB` system wide (for instance, it can set the proper paths to look for `LibB` then call the CMake-provided `FindLibB`): don’t know how, risk of imposing the wrong logic to unrelated projects.

---

NB From the comments I understand that my configuration file is not correct. Yet my goal is to keep a `CMakeLists.txt` as generic as possible, so I'd like a way to handle the exception for `LibB` without breaking this genericity (is there a way to use a default configuration template as I'm doing, and add special-case code in it?). Besides, I realize by looking at CMake documentation for packaging (which was of no help for me, with respect to dependency management) that, though my goal was to have a relocatable package, I'm not doing it properly.

Comment: "My Guess is that, in SomeApp, Cmake is doing a find_package, in CONFIG mode" - You could easily check that guess by inspecting the line from the CMake output where it informs about finding the package. If the reported name ends with `.cmake`, then the package is found via CONFIG mode. Hints to the `find_package` in that mode are described in the [CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html). Hints to the `find_package` in MODULE mode are package-specific. So, for search a solution you (and we) should know the **details**.

Comment: You attempt to *describe* your code, as if you are perfectly understand it and are able to describe all its **aspects related to the problem**. But would you perfectly understand your code, then you won't have so many "I don't understand" in your post, don't you think so? Do not *describe* the code which you have. Instead, show it (add to the question post) **as is**.

Comment: @Tsyvarev in `SomeApp` `CMake` only is only reporting the results of direct calls to `find_package`, not indirect ones. But dumping all CMake variable, I'm finding this one `GDAL_CONSIDERED_CONFIGS=C:/<Msys2Path>/ucrt64/lib/cmake/gdal/GDALConfig.cmake`

Comment: Precision: in previous comment, I made a test with LibB being GDAL

Comment: "CMake only is only reporting the results of direct calls to find_package, not indirect ones." - By "indirect" call you mean the `find_dependency` call inside the config file of **your library** libA, don't you? "I naively thought that when I declared a dependency, it’s path were registered also." - Why do you think so, if you explicitly have written that `find_dependency` call?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I see your point,thx. I forget that my config file generation is automated. I'm editing right now my question by adding the corresponding code. And I'm starting to understand my misbehavior (but still need a hand for a fix).

Comment: Before `find_dependency(GDAL)` in your config file you may implement the same logic, as you have in your `CMakeLists.txt` before the `find_package(GDAL)`. Not sure what kind of "risk of conflicting link in case of diamond-like dependency" you are talking about. Alternatively, you may implement any other behavior of searching the proper installation of GDAL. That behavior depends on your needs, so I don't understand why do you ask us.

Comment: BTW, it is not quite correct to pass REQUIRED to `find_dependency` call. With that keyword absence of GDAL will fail CMake configuration even in case, when SomeLib is not required for the outer package (that is, `find_package(SomeLib)` is used without REQUIRED).

Comment: @Tsyvarev, Thx for your insights, I edited my question to give a bit more context on why I need a hand. I try to have a quite generic CMakeLists and, 1- I'm realizing that I'm not doing so well, 2- I need help to manage exceptions (such as giving a specific logic to find dependency)